# WPF SelectedIndex and IsSelected doesn't sync

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, listboxitem

```
<ListBox  Grid.Column="1"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedListIndex}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" >       
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
               <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This is my xaml,  "SelectedListIndex" is a property binding from the viewmodel and I update him.
I want to show only the selected item, the visibility should update with the trigger.
When I removed the trigger, the selected item change. but when I put the trigger the visibility doesn't update.

Comment: Maybe because `IsSelected` is boolean and you're checking if it's 1. Also how do you expect user to select any item if all will be `Collapsed` by default?

Comment: I have 'Next' & 'Prev' buttons, +/- 1 the index.

Comment: Also instead of `DataTrigger` use `Trigger`: `<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">`

Comment: (You can see now the new code)Changed, and I can see the first item. but when I change the SelectedIndex there isn't any change.

Comment: Does `SelectedListIndex` raise `PropertyChanged` event of `INotyfyPropertyChanged` interface when changed?

Comment: Yes, public int SelectedListIndex
        {
            get { return selectedListIndex; }
            set { selectedListIndex = value; onPropertyChanged("SelectedListIndex"); }
        }

Comment: I put the relevant code, you can copy the code and change the value 'SelectedListIndex' in the viewmodel and see the issue.